# Formato de fecha MM-DD-YYYY convertir a YYYY-DD-MM DateTimePicker.js

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, datetimepicker

tengo un pequeño problemilla que he intentado solventar pero no he logrado. Siempre hago lo mejor de mi antes de acudir aca y les agradeceria muchisimo sus consejos.

La situacion es: Tengo un datetimepicker para seleccionar una fecha del calendario, cuando lo selecciono, automaticamente me lo carga con el formato mm-dd-yyyy. Mi objetivo, es poder guardar esa fecha en la base de datos mysql , sin embargo, esta tiene el tipo de dato Date que es yyyy-mm-dd. Como pudiese hacer para que el usuario al seleccionar una fecha le muestre en el calendario el formato mm-dd-yyyy pero que a la base de datos la envie como yyyy-mm-dd?
Anexo el codigo:

```
<form id="frmactu"><div class="input-group date">
<input type="text" id="datetimepicker1" name="datetimepicker1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required>
</div></form><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnActualizar').click(function(){
        datos=$('#frmactu').serialize();
        if($('#datetimepicker1').val()==""){
            swal("ERROR!", "NO PUEDE ESTAR VACIO LA FECHA!", "error");
            return false;   
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:datos,
            url:"archivos/actualizar.php",
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    $('#tablaDatatable2').load('tablita.php');
                    swal("actualizado!","TODO ha sido actualizdo","success");
                }else{
                    swal("ERROR!","hubo un error","error");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});</script>
```

Y el script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    //format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', Si habilito esta linea, el calendario mostraria ese formato y necesito que muestre el mm-dd-yyyy he ahi la razon por que esta comentado.
    format: 'L',
}); </script>
```

EDICION:

En el archivo actualizar.php recibo los siguiente:

```
<?php 
require_once "../clases/conexion.php";
require_once "../clases/funciones.php";
$obj= new funciones();

$datos=array(
    $_POST['datetimepicker1'],
    $_POST['id']
            );

echo $obj->actualizar($datos);
?>
```

Y en el archivo de funciones.php

```
public function actualizar($datos){
        $obj= new conectar();
        $conexion=$obj->conexion();
                $sql="UPDATE agenda set fecha='$datos[0]',
                            where id='$datos[1]'";
                return mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            }
```

Quiero agradecer a todos los que con su valioso tiempo dedicaron unos segundos para leer mi post y los consejos que pudiera recibir. Gracias de antemano a todos!

Comment: Agrega como recibes la fecha en PHP

Comment: agregado el codigo php compañero. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo `actualizar.php` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
...

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $_POST['datetimepicker1']); //Se crea una fecha con el formato que recibes de la vista.
$fechaFormateada = $date->format('Y-m-d'); //Obtienes la fecha en el formato deseado.

$datos=array(
    $fechaFormateada,
    $_POST['id']
);
...
```

Documentación de [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Respuesta orientada del sitio en Ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307081/8451749